# Modal bootstrap doesn't update its content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I'm implementing some kind of messenger for an application in Rails that works this way: the current user has a list with the people he chatted with and when he clicks on one item, a bootstrap modal with the conversation appears. The problem is that no matters on what item(user he chatted with) he clicks the same conversation appears in the modal (to be more specific: the conversation he has with the first user in the list). This means that the modal's content never gets update.
I have to mention that the  problem is with the view because the data that comes from the server is correct.

Here's the view:

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
      <div class="list-group-item">                    
          <div class="row-picture">
              <%= image_tag conversation[:buddy].user_detail.picture.url, alt: "img", class: "circle"%>
          </div>
          <div class="row-content">
             <h3 class="list-group-item-heading"><%= link_to conversation[:buddy].name, conversation[:buddy] %></h3>
             <p class="list-group-item-text"><%= conversation[:last_reply].reply %></p>
             <p class="text-muted"><small><%= conversation[:last_reply].created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M ")%></small></p>

             <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#show-conversation" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Click to see conversation"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>                           
             <div class="modal fade" id="show-conversation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
                  <div class="modal-dialog text-left">
                       <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Messages!</h4>              
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                 <div class="list-group  scroll-modal">
                                      <% messages = conversation[:conversation_replies] %>
                                           <% messages.each do |message| %>
                                                <%= message.reply %>
                                          <% end %>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
  <div class="list-group-separator"></div>   
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make use of [reload](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload) to check whether you have the latest data or not.
i assume you are able to get an array of `conversations` in `@conversations`.So even **if reload is not helping you out** try to get the relevant conversation by checking something like:-

```
if current_user.chatted_with.includes(user_1)
  //show the chats else chat don't exists  
end
```

Also verify that it is an array of ActiveRecord objects..so access it using `dot` operator like:-

```
       <% @conversation.conversation_replies.each do | messages|  %>
          <% messages.each do |message| %>
           <%= message.reply %>
       <% end %>
```

Comment: I've figured out something: if  I simply display the conversations in the view (not in modals) its content is correct (every user with his relevant conversation). So the problem is with the modal that doesn't update its content.